# XPATH works in Chrome, but not in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to scrape a page. Sorry, I can't disclose the link because of my job's non-disclosure agreement.

```
 print response.xpath('//tr')
```

But it's weird, the XPATH only works on Chrome Dev Tools, but not on Scrapy. I checked the scraped HTML via `response.body`, and the HTML is normal.

Comment: The XPATH works also in FireFox. So maybe you can post your complete spider code so that potential errors show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. It turns out the HTML is broken and Scrapy can't fix it on its own, so it needs Beautiful Soup help. I do it like this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fixed_html = str(BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml"))

print Selector(text=fixed_html).xpath('//*')
```

Comment: An alternative is to use [html5lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib).

Comment: Yes, I would trust html5lib to get it right before beautifulsoup.